# I want to access the values of the keys of an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using an API and I'm getting the response of it on success function as a data.

I'm trying to use which only gives me the "keys" of all objects but not there values, so my question is: can I get the values using below approach?

I have got the "keys" of all objects using JavaScript's `object.key()` method but now I want to get their values too.

Here is the response. I have taken a snippet of response here which I got in console.

```
division: Object
active: 1
country: "United States"
lat: 42.3584647
lon: -71.05962
name: "Boston"
url: "http://yipit.com/boston/"
```

Below the function written to get the key of an object:

```
function getvalues(data){
    for(var i = 0;i <= data.response.deals.length-1; i++){
        var obj = [];
        var num = i + 1;
        var keyArray = Object.keys(data.response.deals[i].division);
        $('#empid h6').html(keyArray);
        //here i get the keys of objects which is country,lat,lon etc.
        console.log("value of keyArray "+num+" is "+keyArray);
    }    
}
```

Comment: See there how you did `...deals[i]` in a loop? Well do the same thing with your array of keys!

Comment: @Arun P Johny hey bro there

Comment: it won't work in IE < 9

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function getvalues(data){
    $.each(data.response.deals, function(i, deal){
        var keys = [], values = [];
        $.each(deal, function(key, value){
            keys.push(key);
            values.push(value);
        });

        console.log('keys ' + (i + 1) + ' is ' + keys);
        console.log('values ' + (i + 1) + ' is ' + values);
    });
}
```

Comment: why put them into a new array ? THe OP justs want to access the return ed value ... ?

Comment: @Kingisback what is the actual requirement

Comment: By using api  got the response and in that response i got 19 object and from each object i have displayed single image and all these 19 images r at the bottom  and at above u can see in grey panel there are decriptions in it and this grey panel description is all from one object that is object no. 0

Comment: now what exactly i want is when i hover on image 1 .i want to display the description of object 1 and when i hover on image 2 i want to display the decription of object 2 and so on..

Comment: is description part of the division object

Comment: is it possible and if can pls help on it

Comment: still I'm not clear on why you want the keys and values in an array

Comment: @Arun P Johny no no its an another object

Comment: also how is the images mark created and how is the hover function and where do you want teh description to appear

Answer (score 0):

The Underscore library has all sort of nice helpers for going functional, also a [#values()](http://underscorejs.org/#values) helper:

```
> myObj= { division: 'Division',
  name: 'Boston',
  url: 'http://yipit.com/boston/' }

> _.values(myObj);
[ 'Division',
  'Boston',
  'http://yipit.com/boston/' ]
```

Answer (score -1):

This will display all the values associated with the keys :

```
var myObject = data.response.deals[i].division;
    for (var key in myObject ) {
      if (myObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        alert(key + " is " + myObject[key]);
        alert(key + " is " + myObject.key);
      }
    }
```

To call a "key" on a an object (which is actually a function or property) you can do either `myObject[key]`, or `myObject.key`